# Adding folder to cache manifest play framework

Tags: playframework

I have a folder name called Images in my project it has five images.

Say img1,img2,img3,img4,img5. How can i add the folder images instead of adding each img like below

```
CACHE MANIFEST
/img1.png
/img2.png
/img3.png
/img4.png
/img5.png

NETWORK:
*
```

Comment: This isn't very clear. Where is this folder? Is it in the project? Do you want to save these images from the application? Access them?

Comment: Yes folder is in project and i want to access it through cache manifest